# While building the archive for ios app from jenkins getting the codesign build issue

Tags: xcodebuild

While building the ios app from jenkins-

command i am running -

xcodebuild -workspace astercore.xcworkspace 
-scheme astercore clean archive -configuration release 
-sdk iphoneos -archivePath astercore.xcarchive

For the above command I am getting below error -

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 40A8326947BD81D0F60EEBBAEB116D66417734EA --entitlements /Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/astercore-hawlwxlqxkigmpgwopemrlgatfkl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/astercore/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/astercore.build/Release-iphoneos/InsiderNotificationService.build/InsiderNotificationService.appex.xcent --generate-entitlement-der /Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/astercore-hawlwxlqxkigmpgwopemrlgatfkl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/astercore/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/InsiderNotificationService.appex

19:31:37  Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: Nishant Gupta (6RLF9LXTVJ)"
19:31:37  /Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/astercore-hawlwxlqxkigmpgwopemrlgatfkl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/astercore/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/InsiderNotificationService.appex: errSecInternalComponent

19:31:37  Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

I tried everything which is given on internet like using security unlock-keychain command.
I also checked the certificates in keychain access.

All I have tried still it is failing though when i run in without jenkins on local it runs without codesign command failure.

Any help will be appreciated.